# Page Redirect after X seconds wait using Flask-python/jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to redirect to another page after staying in a page for x seconds. is it possible to do using python or jinja in flask.A code sinppet can be Helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider embedding some javascript code in your jinja template which can do that work for you. Embeded javascript code will look something like this.

```
<script>    
     window.setTimeout(function(){

       // Move to a new location or you can do something else
       window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";

       }, 5000);

 </script>
```